# Existe algum método em Java equivalente ao PadRight() do C#?

Tags: java

Preciso preencher uma string com espaços em branco caso não utilize todo o espaço.

No C#, resumidamente eu faço da seguinte forma:

```
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("                     RELATÓRIO GERAL DE DIFERENÇAS              ");
        Console.WriteLine($"         DO DIA {data1.getDia()} de {nome_mes.Item1.ToUpper()} DE {data1.getAno()} AO DIA {data2.getDia()} DE {nome_mes2.Item1.ToUpper()} DE {data2.getAno()}");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine($"DIFERENÇA EM DIA(S):      ......................... {diferenca.ToString().PadRight(bteQtdWhiteSpace, ' ')} dia(s)");
        Console.WriteLine($"DIFERENÇA EM SEMANA(S):   ......................... {Math.Round(diferenca / 7).ToString().PadRight(bteQtdWhiteSpace, ' ')} semana(s)*");
```

Comment: o `StringUitls` tem o `rightPad`, e daria pra fazer algo usando `String.format()` também

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o StringUtils,

```
StringUtils.rightPad(minhaString, 10)
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#rightPad(java.lang.String,%20int,%20char)